# How does the EM-field really look like in the foci?

Tags: maxwell-equations, geometric-optics, specific-reference

In geometric optics, the ancient Greeks and Descartes have learned us that...

...a parabolic mirror reflects lightrays coming in from infinity all towards its focus.

...an ellipsoidal mirror (with one longer and two shorter axes of equal length) will focus lightrays emanating from one of its foci into its other focus.

...(less known) a vacuum-glass interface shaped as a [Cartesian oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_oval#Applications_in_optics) revolved around a symmetry axis may refract (or lense) lightrays coming in from infinity along the symmetry axis into a single focus.

**Q: Have these arrangements/configurations been "solved" also at the level of the full Maxwell equations (with appropriate idealized boundary conditions etc.)? Does the EM-field/Poynting vector/energy density still diverge at the foci (or does the wave-character entail a regularizing 'uncertainty principle')?**

N.B. Since the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) can be solved in ellipsoidal and parabolic coordinates (through separation of variables), I suspect that my questions about the mirrors must make an easy-to-tackle project. On the other hand, I have no idea how to start with the one on the oval-shaped lense...

Comment: Yes, these fields have been solved.  There is no singularity.   The field is limited in its physical extent by the wave nature of EM waves.   And there is an "uncertainty principle" at work relating the cross section of the field at focus to the size of the lens that's doing the focusing (and the wavelength).    This question deserves a long answer.   I'll see if can find time to do it, but with luck someone else will.  :-)

Comment: An answer to this question discusses it. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342043/37364

Comment: @garyp: well? Any reference or link?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-17-11-2081)

Abstract: "We derive a solution to the problem of a plane electromagnetic wave focused by a parabolic mirror. The solution is obtained from the Stratton-Chu integral by solving a boundary-value problem. Our solution can be considered self-consistent.* We also derive the far-field, i.e., Debye, approximation of our formulas. The solution shows that when the paraboloid is infinite, its focusing properties exhibit a dispersive behavior; that is, the structure of the field distribution in the vicinity of the focus strongly depends on the wavelength of the illumination. We show that for an infinite paraboloid the confinement of the focused energy worsens, with the energy distribution spreading in the focal plane."

*I don't know what they mean by "self-consistent".