# As we all know a convex lens doesn't exactly converge all rays parallel to it's axis on a single point. So I want to find one such figure

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

Writing a differential equation for such a figure is an uncomplicated task. It can be accomplished by using snell's law. But the resulting equation probably isn't solvable. I put it in wolfram alpha and it didnt even show it's graph. May be not it's solution, but I'd like to see its graph at least.

Comment: What kind of a "figure" do you want or what is your differential equation?

Comment: Just compute the refraction of a few parallel incoming rays with different distance from the axis, and see that they don't converge at a single point. Include more and more of them until you're satisfied.

Comment: This might help - [Is there a more accurate form of the mirror equation $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342043/37364)

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal lens in the limit of large refractive index and thickness = 0, the rays will (I believe) converge to points.  Can you express your full equation to first order in thickness, to get something that is solvable and hopefully more easily plotted?